# Sockets with Tor and Python

Tags: python, tor

Hello I am building an IM P2P client/server in Python and would like to use Tor as a proxy for it the server runs using Threads while the client runs at the same time

Does the server running on the local system need to listen to Tor? If so how do I do this? How do I make the client connect to a remote system using Tor?

I have searched for some examples but they lead to a library that seems to be really awkward to download

Here is the relevant server/client code

```
    #Client Connection
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((str(self.CLIENT_HOST).strip(), self.CLIENT_PORT))
```

```
    #Server
    source_ip = ''
    #socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    PORT = 9001
    ### Initialize socket
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((source_ip, PORT))
    # 
    server_socket.listen(5)
```

Any ideas are greatly welcomed and appreciated

Comment: You might want to go back through old answers and accept some of them if you would like to continue to receive help.

Comment: My apologies I had no idea how to do that or that was how this system worked (learn something new everyday)

Comment: No problem, just wanted to let you know so that you had the best chance of getting an answer.